# What is the meaning of size in celestial bodies?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy

I read about a star collapsed to a size of 12 km. Does the size mean that the new radius is 12 km or the diameter of the star

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the context. In this case, it's probably the radius, since that's what we tend to use in equations. Eg, in Newtonian physics, the gravitational force between 2 bodies depends on the centre to centre distance:

$$F=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$
and so the gravitational acceleration on the surface of a planet or star is
$$a=\frac{GM}{r^2}$$

And when talking about star collapse, it's natural for a journalist or astronomer to use radius rather than diameter because it's smaller, and therefore more impressive. ;)

OTOH, when talking about how big a giant star is, a journalist may use the diameter because it sounds bigger. An astronomer would almost always use the radius when discussing the *structure* of a celestial body. However, they are quite likely to describe the appearance of the body in a telescope in terms of its angular diameter. But that's measured in degrees, minutes, and seconds, or radians, not kilometres or miles.